# If A, B, and C are set and $A \subset B ,B \subset C \rightarrow A \subset C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering how to show the following proposition

**If A, B, and C are set and $A \subset  B ,B \subset C \rightarrow A \subset C$**

**My proof**

Let x be any integer.

If $x\in A$ then $x\in B$ because all element of A are in B.  If $x \in B \rightarrow x\in C$ because all element of B are in C.

Since B contains A and C contains B, then C contains A logically.

the end

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Sure, but why is $x$ taken to be an integer? What you prove is true for any kind of sets.

Comment: I am not sure I guess I can say let x be any element of a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the last sentence.  You simply draw the conclusion that $x \in A\implies x \in C $, and so $A\subset C$.

Polishing it up a tad:

Let $x$ be any element in $A$. Then, $x \in A\implies x\in B$ because $A \subset B$. Then $x \in B \implies x\in C$, since $B\subset C$.

Therefore, $$x\in A \implies x \in C$$ and by definition of a subset, $A\subset C$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\underbrace{x \in A \implies x \in B}_{\text{since} \ A \subset B} \implies x \in C \ \ (\text{since } B \subset C),$$ so ( by the transitive property of implications) $x \in A \implies x \in C$ for any $x$, so $A \subset C $.

$\square$

A couple of notes: $x$ does not have to be an integer; it doesn't even have to be a number.

$A$ could be the set of all people in the world and $x$ could be an arbitrary person.

This proof shows that, for any *element* $x$ which is in $A$, $x$ is automatically in $C$.

Also, don't finish with "the end"- it's not a fairy tale!

A nice, concise way to end a proof is with a $\square$.